# How to find today's modified file in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Please help me with command to list the files modified today.
I have tried the `dir /TW` command but it lists all the files in the directory.

All the files listed for the `dir /TW` command:

[image]

Comment: `dir /TW | find "%date%"`?

Comment: @JosefZ i tried that command , i didnt get any results!

Comment: Sorry, a question mark in my hint indicates my own doubts as it depends on the `%date%` format and appearance (according to your locale and personal preferences)… Check using `echo "%date%"`. In any case, you can use _literally_  `dir /TW | find "07/25/2019"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
forfiles /d +[today's date, formatted as yyyy/mm/dd]
```

This result will show only the files modified today in the current directory

Also, the result will only list the file names

To see the full path, use:

```
forfiles /d +[yyyy/mm/dd] /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

See forfiles /? for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using `forfiles`, you can do the following:

```
FORFILES /S /D +14/03/2022 /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

In order to know today's date, you can use `DATE /T`.
You put it's result in a variable and use this in the `forfiles` command.

For your information:

- `/S` : also investigate subdirectories
- `/D <date>` : show files, modified later than that timestamp
- `/M *.txt`  : filter on extension
- `/C "cmd /c echo @path"`: the `/C` gives you the opportunity to launch a command (like `echo`, `cp`, `del`, ...), the `@path` is a `forfiles` parameter, containing the full path of the found file.